# jdbc connection sqlite return type of Connection class

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

```
public class SqliteConnect {
    private static SqliteConnect conn ;

    public static Connection dbConnector(){

        try{
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Downloads\\InternArchive\\InternArchive\\InternDB\\InternshipDB.sqlite");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Veritabanına Başarı ile Bağlanıldı!");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;

        }
    }
}
```

I get an error : this method must return a result of type Connection. I know I can add return type or void, but I need this method.

Comment: if you add `return conn;` at the end of the try block, it will compile. Whether or not that's what you want, who knows.

Comment: when i add return conn at the end; the other classes that use this method gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

As the method is not void, you must return the method type which is Connection

```
public class SqliteConnect {

    //private static SqliteConnect conn ;

    public Connection dbConnector(){

        Connection conn = null;

        try{
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Downloads\\InternArchive\\InternArchive\\InternDB\\InternshipDB.sqlite");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Veritabanina Basari ile Baglanildi!");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;

        } 
        return conn;        
    }
}
```